# SAS PCA first 10 eigenvalues only explains 10% of the variance

Tags: pca, sas, finance

I am running a Principal Component Analysis on intra-day second level returns of all the stocks that trade in the U.S.

The matrix is constructed as

[image]

where each row is the return of all stocks in each second. For example:

```
9:30:00 (SPY, S&P500, AAPL, MSFT, …, BABA, BIDU, AMZN)
9:30:01 (SPY, S&P500, AAPL, MSFT, …, BABA, BIDU, AMZN)
```

However, the PCA results are kind of weird.

[image]

It seems that the first 10 eigenvalues only explain 10% of the total variance.

Is this normal? If capital asset pricing model [CAPM](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/capm.asp) holds, I expect a market portfolio that explains most of the variance in the daily stock return data. But this is not the case.

I am using SAS to run the PCA. The code I am using:

```
  ods output Eigenvectors=PRINCEEV Eigenvalues=PRINCEEVAL;
  proc princomp data=REPLACED;
  run;
  ods output close;
```

Comment: How many variables are there? Presumably many more than 10. Whether this is surprising is an empirical question for finance/economics forums (very many members here, including me, won't even be able to say what CAPM means).

Comment: There are 3000 variables. Is this a problem?

Comment: I am basically seeing every stock that trades on the market at an variable.

Comment: 3000 variables are the context we need to think about this. I am not an economist and I am not surprised. You may get much better informed reactions from others. As said, I don't see this as a statistical question.

Comment: Cross posted @ Quant.SE [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34923/sas-pca-first-10-eigenvalues-only-explains-10-of-the-variance).

Comment: These aren't "daily stock return data"--they appear to be returns *second by second*.  I wasn't aware that the CAPM made any assertions about returns on such a tiny time scale, where it would be much more plausible that the behavior is virtually uncorrelated.

Comment: @whuber Yes it is second by second returns. Are you saying that the returns are a random walk and not explained too well by PCA?

Comment: That is both what one would expect of such data and what the PCA appears to be telling you.  If your stocks comprised a popular index and if it were possible to buy and sell every one in the index simultaneously--to within a fraction of a second-we might expect more correlation than that, but at this time scale you would likely just be studying noise rather than the signal.  As a check, you might do PCA on the one-minute or one-hour or one-day changes: the eigenvalues ought to increase substantially.